# множественный фильтр по данным из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста! Не могу справится с задачей:

есть две таблицы 1 Данные 2 Значения
в первой набор данных поля '1 2 3 4 5 ...' во второй значения для фильтра 'а'
как выбрать уникальные записи по фильтру поля 'а' таблицы значения из таблицы данные
всяко пробовал склоняюсь к

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Данные
WHERE
  данные.1 in (select a from Значения) and
  данные.2 in (select a from Значения) and
  ............;
```

либо

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Данные
WHERE
  (select a from Значения where значения.а=данные.1) and
  (select a from Значения where значения.а=данные.2) and
  .........;
```

все работает если все подзапросы возвращают данные
если в таблице значения нет значений для фильтрации вся конструкция возвращает пусто так как получается and null

Возможно ли использовать для каждого подзапроса if для отображения is null?
все перепробовал не получается как отработать если хоть один подзапрос пустой по нему is null или на крайняк like '*'

Идея в том, что если не задан какой либо фильтр или группа из данных фильтров выдать выборку and по остальным

Comment: Покажите пример исходных данных и требуемый результат для именно этих данных.

Comment: Странные требования. Если фильтр не возвращает данных, то проигнорировать фильтр